# Looking for Information on the Bluetooth LE "Indicate" Behavior

Tags: ios, swift, macos, core-bluetooth, obd-ii

I'm working on [a Bluetooth LE project](https://github.com/RiftValleySoftware/RVS_GTDriver), and it's going fairly well.

However, I am now up to supporting [a Kiwi device](https://www.plxdevices.com/ProductDetails.asp?ProductCode=897346002092), and the rules are changing a bit.

Before, I would use various combinations of BLE read and BLE write properties on vendor-specific GATT characteristics, but I think that Kiwi might use the Indicate property.

I can find almost no documentation on Indicate, and how to work with it. Apple doesn't seem to have any mention of it in their docs, and the Bluetooth spec barely mentions it.

I must have missed the documents on that property, and how it differs from read. From reading the (very short) blurbs on it, it sounds just like read, but my explorations of the Kiwi device don't seem to be supporting it.

I know that this is a bit of an "open-ended" question, but I need to learn more about Indicate, and how it is supported in CoreBluetooth.

I would really appreciate any pointers. I just need a bit of a breadcrumb trail that I can follow.

Thanks!

Comment: Indicate is like notify; once you enable notifications for the characteristic you will receive a call to your delegate's [didUpdateValue](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheraldelegate/1518708-peripheral) function when the peripheral updates the characteristic value. It is typically used where the value can change at any time and polling (continually reading to look for changes) is inefficient

Comment: Awesome! If you phrase that as an answer, I'll greencheck you! Thanks!

Comment: Reading up on that, it says that [the setNotifyValue method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheral/1518949-setnotifyvalue) only works on notifications. I assume that notify and indicate are synonymous, but the bits of docs I've seen, treat them as separate, and their flags are different.

Comment: Indicate requires the central to acknowledge that it has received the new value while notify does not. From a Core Bluetooth perspective your app can treat them the same.  The Core Bluetooth framework takes care of acknowledgement for you.  https://www.onethesis.com/2015/11/21/ble-introduction-notify-or-indicate/

Comment: Thanks so much for that link!

Comment: @Paulw11 Just wanted to remind you that I'm happy to greencheck your answer. Your response was perfect for me. I know that it wasn't the most challenging question, but I needed that answer, and you delivered. Thanks!

Comment: https://www.onethesis.com/ble-introduction-notify-or-indicate/ is the new link @Paulw11 . Very nice link by the way :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Indicate* and *Notify* are similar; They provide a new characteristic value to the central when the peripheral changes that value without the central needing to perform inefficient polling.  The difference at the Bluetooth layers is that the central needs to acknowledge receipt of an *Indicate* to the peripheral, while with *Notify* no such acknowledgement takes place.

Since the Core Bluetooth framework abstracts the underlying Bluetooth stack from your app you don't need to worry about the difference between *Indicate* and *Notify* - Core Bluetooth handles it for you.